# Allowing duplicating users with same user_login and user_email

Tags: plugin-development, users, login, user-registration

I would need a solution that the system would accept duplicates on user_login. I found a plugin for user_email duplicates, but I also need for user_login.

Any idea is welcome,

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea. In addition to whatever your duplicate email plugin has done in terms of overriding get_user_by and the useremail cache you'd also have to change the login cookies to not expect a unique user ID.

Comment: If you really do need to do this I'd suggest sticking to unique user names in the database and internally, in the login cookies etc., but add an alias user login in user meta and accept those during login. There might still be a few places where the user would see their internal user login e.g. in the REST API which you could patch too. But that would be simpler than making sure all of the core code is happy with non-unique logins. And I'd still advise against it.